# ¿como puedo eliminar varias filas seleccionadas a la vez en un datagridview c#?

Tags: mysql, c#, datagridview, eliminar

estoy realizando una app de formulario donde tengo almacenados varios productos en una base de datos mysql, el formulario tiene una opcion para borrar productos.
quiero permitir el borrado de varias filas de productos seleccionados a la vez.
cuando se seleccionan varias filas a la vez, solo se elimina una fila.
adjunto mi codigo para mas ayuda:

```
 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string rowFirstCell;
        //recibir los datos de fila seleccionados
        if (dtgvOfertas.Rows.Count <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("no se puede elminar ningun registro", 
                "preguntar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("¿Borrar registros" +
                " seleccionados?", "Preguntar", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, 
                MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)

            {
                return;



            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dtgvOfertas.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
                // Recorrer los datos adquiridos
                {

                    rowFirstCell = 
                        dtgvOfertas.SelectedRows[i]
                        .Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                    // Filtra los campos obligatorios o
                    // identificadores únicos en cada fila
                    try
                    {
                        conectar();
                        string query = "delete from OFERTAS where codigo='"
                        + rowFirstCell + "'";
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

                        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("data deleted");
                            dtgvOfertas.DataSource = null;
                            desconectar();
                            cargadatos();


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            desconectar();
                            MessageBox.Show("data not deleted");

                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        desconectar();
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }     

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

este seria el procedimiento que he intentado. he estoy recorriendo todas las filas seleccionadas pero no entiendo porque no las elimina y solamente elimina una de todas ellas.

Comment: Hola Alex como seleccionas varias filas mediante un check delante de cada fila? de no ser así deberías poner un check delante de cada fila y después al traer todo tu datagridview y con un for lo recorres y por cada fila validas si esta chequeado y lo eliminas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

identifico que tu problema podría ser al momento de eliminar el registro satisfactoriamente , puesto que mandas a actualizar de nuevo el grid, haciendo que la selección múltiple que había anteriormente se quite, ya que cuando añades un nuevo origen de datos al datagrid, este por defecto te selecciona un solo registro.

Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string rowFirstCell;
        //recibir los datos de fila seleccionados
        if (dtgvOfertas.SelectedRows.Count <= 0)//Contar si hay filas seleccionadas
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No hay filas seleccionadas!",
                "Eliminando registro...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("¿Borrar registros" +
                " seleccionados?", "Preguntar", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,
                MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)

            {
                return;



            }
            else
            {
                DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection Selecciondas = dtgvOfertas.SelectedRows;
                int filasAfectadas = 0;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow i in Selecciondas)// Recorrer los datos adquiridos
                {
                    rowFirstCell = i.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

                    // Filtra los campos obligatorios o
                    // identificadores únicos en cada fila
                    try
                    {
                        conectar();
                        string query = "delete from OFERTAS where codigo='"
                        + rowFirstCell + "'";
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

                        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                        {
                            filasAfectadas++;//Incrementa uno si se elimino correctamente
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            desconectar();
                            MessageBox.Show($"data not deleted {rowFirstCell }");//Mostramos el codigo que no se pudo eliminar

                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        desconectar();
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }

                }
                if (filasAfectadas > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("data deleted");
                    dtgvOfertas.DataSource = null;
                    desconectar();
                    cargadatos();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

espero te sea de ayuda!

Comment: lo acabo de implementar en mi codigo del formulario, y el resultado es muy bueno ya que puedo borrar todas las filas seleccionadas. muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegra que te haya sido de utilidad, Saludos.